# how to get latest timestamp data

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am new to influx db, please help me with query?

I have below like data in influx where same `Name` data (A1, A2) can be available for multiple time.

I need only latest time stamp data (row 3,4,5) if same data is available in multiple time stamp and the new data (A3). Is such query available in influx?

this query only gives one record,

```
SELECT time, Name, value  FROM "data"  order by time desc limit 1
```

[image]

Comment: can you tell what are the tags and fields in this AssetAssetType measurement?

Comment: Thanks @Robert. `value' is field here and Name is tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the InfluxDB's [last](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#last) function to achieve this.

```
SELECT LAST("value") FROM AssetAssetType  GROUP BY "Name"
```

Comment: how to get Name and value both?  I am not getting correct output for `SELECT LAST("value"), LAST("Name") FROM AssetAssetType  GROUP BY "Name"`

Comment: GROUP BY "Name" should give both value and Name. You can try this also, SELECT "Name", LAST("value") FROM AssetAssetType  GROUP BY "Name"